# zoom slider bar for Angular 2+

Tags: angular, slider, zooming

So I want something like this:

https://codepen.io/edouardbarthelemy/pen/aBZpdv

```
<panzoomwidget panzoom-id="PanZoom" style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;z-index:1"></panzoomwidget>
    <panzoom id="PanZoom" config="panzoomConfig" model="panzoomModel" style="width:800px; height: 600px">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mvindahl/angular-pan-zoom/master/demo/images/shark_attack.jpg" style="position:absolute" />
        <svg style="position:absolute" width="800px" height="600px">
            <rect ng-repeat="rect in rects" ng-attr-x="{{rect.x}}" ng-attr-y="{{rect.y}}" ng-attr-width="{{rect.width}}" ng-attr-height="{{rect.height}}" rx="10" ry="10" style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:rgb(255,0,0)" />
        </svg>
    </panzoom>
```

only for angular 2+. I'm relatively new to Angular 2+, being formerly an AngularJS developer myself, and I've been scouring the interwebs for the past couple hours looking for like an npm package or something that I can use that does this. Anybody got any pointers?